# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in django

Tags: django, nginx

I am using django Framework on nginx server.

I am getting below error, I have checked, image exists there.

```
<body> 
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /media/drivers/defaults/driver.png was not found on this server.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your STATIC_PATH has been set to point to this directory and that the image within it are served under the url /media/.....

Comment: check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

Comment: Wait, are you serving static files using nginx? please clarify your question, I'll downvote it until it becomes clear enough.